# How to get the value of Primary Key of any table for a particular row

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django Im creating user, and after that I want the PK of the User and then I want to put it into some other table.

I am using the below code

```
id_profile = User.objects.filter(email = email)
id_profile = id_for_profile.values("id")
```

here im getting the output `<QuerySet [{'id': 11}]>`

but i want the Number "11" associated with the variable "id_profile"

How can it be done?

[[SOLVED]]

It is returning a List of Dictionaries, I can access the Values with that way.

or using the answers that were provided below.

Comment: Please post your `models.py`

Comment: id_profile is a queryset that can result 0, 1 or more Users when it is executed, it's not guaranteed that there is exactly one with that email.

Comment: for the Table "User" I didnt create any model. I am just using it from the ``` from django.contrib.auth.models import User ```

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I have used some code to check the email field, if the email already exists in the DB it will not save the user

Comment: Sounds like you have another Model with a ForeignKey to User.  You might want to share that here.

Comment: I am new to Django, currently I didnt use Foreign key concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(email = email)
```

is list.

try with

```
id_profile[0].id
```

or use `get` rather than `filter` method

```
id_profile = User.objects.get(email = email)
```

now it will return a object ,and access the `pk`

```
id_profile.pk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
id_profile = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
pk = id_profile.pk
```

You can also use the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

```
user_pk = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth',model='user').pk
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `email` field is unique you should use a `get` as the model will not return more than one `user` object.

You should use `get_object_or_404`. When the email does not exist an exception will be raised.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

user = get_object_or_404(User, email=email)
# to access the pk you can do this
user.pk
```